# How to create a perfect depth hole?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, sculpting, sculpt

I want to create a perfect depth hole. I tried using boolean and bevel after, but doesn't work...
[image]
[image]

Here is my reference image: 
[image]

Comment: Why not try using inset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mesh I came up with is this one. It could be more rounded but just move the supporting edges away from the corner of the hole to do that. I did not round the object as a whole in the corners but this can be done quite easily.

I started with a plane and subdivided it. I then added a loop around where the hole would be and then deleted the faces. I extruded and added some more supporting edge loops. Finally I added an edge loop inside the hole and scaled it to give the bevelled appearance.

Once completed I added a subdiv x 2

[image: mesh]

[image: object]

Here I added a simple bend deformer to show the flexibility of the mesh for animation etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This topology seems good to me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Posting my suggestion as answer in order to show pictures:
This is another way to do it.

I inset the face, then moved the result to the adequate position.
Then extrude along Y.

Then bevel modifier, add a couple of loopcuts inside the square, apply bevel.

[image]

For this one, I did loop cuts vertically and horizontally. Then extruded the square along Y, added a loop cut inside for bevel not to go crazy, then applied bevel.

[image]